# why do i get syntax error on manage.py makemigrations?

Tags: python, django, migrate, makemigrations

I'm making a test project with python and django (for learning purpose). At some point I have to make a django app called products, then in the models.py file in the "products" app directory I have this code:

```
class Products (models.Model)
     title = models.TextField() 
     description = models.TextField()
     price = models.TextField()
```

and then after adding the new app in the settings file when I attend to make migrations as shown:

```
> python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get is this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
        django.setup()
      File "C:\django\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "C:\django\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
        app_config.import_models()
      File "C:\django\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
      File "C:\django\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\django\mystore\products\models.py", line 5
        class Products(models.Model)
                                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

 "
```

and then the same error occurs whenever I try to use the manage.py file. I don't know what I've done wrong please help me fix this.

Comment: you are missing missing a `:` in `C:\django\mystore\products\models.py`. class definition should e `class A(B):`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a colon after the class declaration.

```
class Products(models.Model):
```

Also, I would caution you on your formatting. Your field names should line up on the left. In Python, two lines that don't line up are considered different blocks of code.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a colon after you declared the class

```
class Products (models.Model)  #<<--- no semicolon
 title = models.TextField() 
 description = models.TextField()
 price = models.TextField()
```

Right code:

```
class Products (models.Model):  #<<---  colon
 title = models.TextField() 
 description = models.TextField()
 price = models.TextField()
```